# Facebook JS API can't logout

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a `localhost` website and script with `FB.logout()`. After some actions, it fails to log me out and I see next error message in console:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/home.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-  Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I searched all StackOverflow and didn't find any working solution. Network inspector shows cancelled near home.php query.
So I understand that the script tries to load the Facebook homepage in a frame, but it can't because it is prohibited. So how can I fix it? Why doesn't `logout()` work for me?

My code

```
// Facebook Basic Example

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '579651098766258',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
};

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));



function testAPI() {
  FB.api('/me', function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    setTimeout(function(){
      FB.logout(); // <-- ERROR
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @AdamAzad Added to my post

Comment: I tried the code with my app it works fine! probably it was a bug

Comment: Did you try on localhost or webserver? @AdamAzad

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 41):

This solution worked for me:

1. Go to Settings tab in your facebook application and in Basic tab scrolldown to +Add Platform
2. Click on +Add Platform and choose Website
3. Add your url of your website (for me, was the same url added on Advanced tab on Redirect URIs)
4. Save changes and test again.

Also I made a youtube video to solve this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CNpLgwa0-c

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me. "Add Platform" really does not mean anything like that to me!

Comment: Appears for me it was clicking "Facebook Login" in the left hand column that revealed the OAuth url location

Comment: I had multiple domains that I wanted FB to acknowledge. It worked for me to add those domains into the "App Domains" field as shown in the picture.

Comment: There is no "Add Platform" link now-a-days

Comment: Currently it is necessary to add the path being used in the "App Domains" input. In my case it looks like this: "https://example.com/testefb/facebookLogin.php"

Answer (score 10):

I had to set the "App Domains" field in the Settings tab within the Facebook's App control panel in order for it to work:

[image]

Comment: You are right, the App Domains and  Site URL on Settings -> Basic, must match.

Answer (score 3):

Update by 2019 May 2nd:

1) The https now is enforced, so you must use https://localhost. http will no longer be available.

2) You need to whitelist your localhost by going to Settings > Basic > Add Plat form and choose "Website"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your HTML looks like, but for me this worked on my logout button:

```
onclick="javascript:FB.logout(function() { window.location.reload() }); return false;"
```

I hope this will help someone out, at least this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Update for 2018**

From the App Dashboard, under the Facebook Login product, click on Quickstart and follow the instructions.  The Logout API call should start working!

[image]

**Note:** I selected WWW and entered `http://localhost:5757/` in the Site URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with **www**.example.com I get this error and without the www (example.com) there is no error...

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me -

1. Go to facebook Login -> quickstart -> www -> set app origin url "https://localhost:4200".

[image]